# How to "publish" my application?

Tags: c#, deployment, publishing

I've completed my little app with some help here on StackOverflow so now I have to give it to the world!

Is there a simple way to do this? My app is just a little .exe file with a .settings file.

I think users don't have to install anything but I may be mistaken.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well as long as your users have the relevant .net framework that is all you should need.

You could look at wrapping the app in an [msi](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Creating-a-.NET-Windows-Installer--Part-1/) or use [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4%28VS.80%29.aspx). I used to use [innoSetup](http://www.innosetup.com) for desktop applications

Edit: in the comments you asked what you have to copy. The answer all your applications dependencies. In your case you've mentioned the exe and the .settings.

You may have other dependencies in other projects, these would need to be installed too that is when you would probably want to consider an installer.

Comment: So I just press Control+Shift+B on my VC#Express, let it build, then copy everything in my bin\Release folder to the end-user? In that folder there is the following: CDLauncher.exe (my program), CDLauncher.exe.config and CDLauncher.pdb. What exactly is the last file and should I keep the three together when deploying?

Comment: A program database (PDB) file is not needed. it is used for debugging.

Comment: You should only need the CDLauncher.exe and if you reference is the .settings file

Comment: So to clarify, I just put the CDLauncher.exe (my program), CDLauncher.exe.config into a .zip and that's it, right?

Comment: but yes just put the CDLauncher.exe (my program), CDLauncher.exe.config

Comment: I would vote for ClickOnce. It generates all the files necessary to deploy your app using the web. And as an added bonus, anytime you publish a new version, if the setting is enabled, the next time someone opens your app it will auto-install the new version.

Comment: (continued) i use it at my job with several internal tools and it works great.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [ClickOnce deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx).

Comment: ClickOnce is by far the easiest way to publish and auto-update a desktop app.